# Connection reset when try to send mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, tls1.2

I'm try to send an email using javax.mail version 1.4.7. This is the code that I'm using to send the mail:

```
String protocollo = "smtps";
String usernamePec = "fromAddress@pec.it";
String passwordPec = "mypassword";
String pecTo = "ToAddress@pec.it";


Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
props.put("mail.smtps.host", "smtps.pec.aruba.it"); // esempio smtp.gmail.com
props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
{
  public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
    return new PasswordAuthentication( usernamePec,passwordPec);
     }
});

 MimeMessage messaggioEmail = new MimeMessage( session );
 MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(messaggioEmail, true);
 helper.setFrom(usernamePec);
 helper.setTo(pecTo);
 helper.setSubject("Test Subject");
 helper.setPriority(1);
 helper.setText("Body Mail ", false);           
 messaggioEmail.saveChanges();
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPMessage mex = new SMTPMessage(messaggioEmail);
 com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport t = 
 (com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport)session.getTransport(protocollo); // <--SMTPS
 t.setStartTLS(true); //<-- impostiamo il flag per iniziare la comunicazione sicura
 t.connect( "smtps.pec.aruba.it", usernamePec,passwordPec);
 t.sendMessage( mex, mex.getAllRecipients());
 t.close();
```

Running this code I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtps.pec.aruba.it, port: 465;
      nested exception is:
        java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1961)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:654)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
        at test.Test.main(Test.java:199)
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)
... 4 more
```

It seems a problem due a bad ssl certificate handshake, any suggestion about this, Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: There might be an issue with your SSL settings. `STARTTLS is different to SSL and TLS. Before encryption was standard, many connections between an email client and the server were done insecurely. This put personal information in danger of being stolen. STARTTLS helped to reduce this risk by taking an existing insecure connection and upgrading it to a secure connection that used SSL/TLS. STARTTLS works with either SSL or TLS.` [reference](https://www.fastmail.com/help/technical/ssltlsstarttls.html).

So you might need to make your connection SSL/TLS encrypted all the way from beginning.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented to OP, there might be an issue with your approach to SSL/TLS connection. Try this example code with your own settings, I've been successfully of using this in quite a many different environments. Or maybe you can just pick the crucial part of the code from example:

```
private void sendMail()
        throws MessagingException, AddressException, IOException {
    String smtpHost = "";
    Integer smtpPort = 465;
    final String from = "me@me.com";
    final String password = "";
    String to = "theOtherGuy@he.com";
    String cc = "";
    String bcc = "";
    String subject = "";
    String bodyText = "";
    List<File> files = null; // Set attachment files if needed

    boolean sslEnable = true;
    boolean startTlsEnable = false;

    String user = "";
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort);

    if (user != null && !user.equals("")) {
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
        properties.put("mail.smtps.user", user);
    } else {
        properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        properties.put("mail.smtps.user", from);
    }
    properties.put("mail.smtp.sendpartial", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtps.host", smtpHost);
    properties.put("mail.smtps.port", smtpPort);
    properties.put("mail.smtps.sendpartial", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.timeout", 30000);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", 60000);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.writetimeout", 15000);

    if (startTlsEnable) {
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtps.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
        properties.put("mail.smtps.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
        properties.put("mail.protocol.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
    }
    if (sslEnable) {
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
        properties.put("mail.smtps.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtps.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
        properties.put("mail.protocol.ssl.trust", smtpHost);
    }

    Session session;
    if (password != null && password.length() > 0) {
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        final String userName = user;
        if (user != null && !user.equals("")) {
            session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName,
                                    password);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(from,
                                    password);
                        }
                    });
        }

    } else {
        session = Session.getInstance(properties);
    }

    MimeMessage mailMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
    try {
        mailMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        throw new AddressException("Invalid FROM address: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    mailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
    mailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, cc);
    mailMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bcc);
    mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mailMessage.setSentDate(new Date());

    // Set the email message text.
    MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messagePart.setContent(bodyText, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    // messagePart.setText(bodyText);
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("mixed");
    multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);

    try {
        if (files != null) {
            for (File file : files) {
                MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                attachmentPart.attachFile(file);
                multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
            }
        }
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new MessagingException(
                "Error attaching files, MessagingException: "
                        + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("Error attaching files: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    mailMessage.setContent(multipart);

    if (password == null || password.length() < 1) {
        Transport.send(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients());
    } else if (user != null && !user.equals("")) {
        Transport.send(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients(), user,
                password);
    } else {
        Transport.send(mailMessage, mailMessage.getAllRecipients(), from,
                password);
    }
}
```

Comment: I try to use your code but I'm getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

First, let's simplify your code.

Change the Session creation to this:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
```

Acquire the Transport like this:

```
 Transport t = session.getTransport(protocollo); // <--SMTPS
```

Remove the call to t.setStartTLS; this is likely the source of your problem.

You're using the "smtps" protocol, which uses SSL when first connecting to the server.  The "STARTTLS" support is for cases when the server requires you to first connect using a plain text connection and then switch to TLS (SSL) after connection.  That's not what you're doing here, and unless your server requires it you don't want to do it.

Comment: I try to modify my code with your suggestion but i get always the same problem

Comment: Post the updated code and the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade the library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello Ale ! Welcome to StackOverflow ! Did you read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page ? I would suggest you the following steps: 1) Ask a question, do not order people trying to help you. 2) Be more specific: what problem do you encounter ? Which version do you want to upgrade to ? 3) What did you try and searched before asking your question ? This way more people would be prone to answering you.